# How to find out if a lazy relation isn't loaded yet, with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

With SQLAlchemy, is there a way to know beforehand whether a relation would be lazy-loaded?
For example, given a lazy parent->children relation and an instance X of "parent", I'd like to know if "X.children" is already loaded, without triggering the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could look at the child's `__dict__` attribute dictionary to check if the data is already there or not.

Answer (score 27):

You can get a list of all unloaded properties (both relations and columns) from `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.instance_state(obj).unloaded`.

See: [Completing object with its relations and avoiding unnecessary queries in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795492/completing-object-with-its-relations-and-avoiding-unnecessary-queries-in-sqlalch)

An easier way is to use `inspect()`, which gives the same results:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
from sqlalchemy.orm import lazyload

user = session.query(User).options(lazyload(User.articles)).first()
ins = inspect(user)

ins.unloaded  # <- set or properties that are not yet loaded
```

Comment: Tested in SQLAlchemy 1.4 and it works. This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Slightly neater than Haes answer (though it effectively does the same thing) is to use hasattr(), as in:

```
>>> hasattr(X, 'children')
False
```

Comment: This doesn't work with current sqlalchemy. `hasattr(obj, field)` is not equivalent to `field in obj.__dict__`.

Comment: I've tested in SQLAlchemy 0.8 and this does work if the object is detached. However if it is attached then using hasattr triggers the lazy load of 'children', which probably isn't what you want. Instead in 0.8 we can use the inspect() call: `res = inspect(X)` `'children' in res.unloaded` - which works whether the object is attached or detached.