# Completing object with its relations and avoiding unnecessary queries in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, eager-loading

I have some database structure; as most of it is irrelevant for us, i'll describe just some relevant pieces. Let's lake Item object as example:

```
items_table = Table("invtypes", gdata_meta,
                    Column("typeID", Integer, primary_key = True),
                    Column("typeName", String, index=True),
                    Column("marketGroupID", Integer, ForeignKey("invmarketgroups.marketGroupID")),
                    Column("groupID", Integer, ForeignKey("invgroups.groupID"), index=True))

mapper(Item, items_table,
       properties = {"group" : relation(Group, backref = "items"),
                     "_Item__attributes" : relation(Attribute, collection_class = attribute_mapped_collection('name')),
                     "effects" : relation(Effect, collection_class = attribute_mapped_collection('name')),
                     "metaGroup" : relation(MetaType,
                                            primaryjoin = metatypes_table.c.typeID == items_table.c.typeID,
                                            uselist = False),
                     "ID" : synonym("typeID"),
                     "name" : synonym("typeName")})
```

I want to achieve some performance improvements in the sqlalchemy/database layer, and have couple of ideas:
1) Requesting the same item twice:

```
item = session.query(Item).get(11184)
item = None (reference to item is lost, object is garbage collected)
item = session.query(Item).get(11184)
```

Each request generates and issues SQL query. To avoid it, i use 2 custom maps for an item object:

```
itemMapId = {}
itemMapName = {}

@cachedQuery(1, "lookfor")
def getItem(lookfor, eager=None):
    if isinstance(lookfor, (int, float)):
        id = int(lookfor)
        if eager is None and id in itemMapId:
            item = itemMapId[id]
        else:
            item = session.query(Item).options(*processEager(eager)).get(id)
            itemMapId[item.ID] = item
            itemMapName[item.name] = item
    elif isinstance(lookfor, basestring):
        if eager is None and lookfor in itemMapName:
            item = itemMapName[lookfor]
        else:
            # Items have unique names, so we can fetch just first result w/o ensuring its uniqueness
            item = session.query(Item).options(*processEager(eager)).filter(Item.name == lookfor).first()
            itemMapId[item.ID] = item
            itemMapName[item.name] = item
    return item
```

I believe sqlalchemy does similar object tracking, at least by primary key (item.ID). If it does, i can wipe both maps (although wiping name map will require minor modifications to application which uses these queries) to not duplicate functionality and use stock methods. Actual question is: if there's such functionality in sqlalchemy, how to access it?

2) Eager loading of relationships often helps to save alot of requests to database. Say, i'll definitely need following set of item=Item() properties:

```
item.group (Group object, according to groupID of our item)
item.group.items (fetch all items from items list of our group)
item.group.items.metaGroup (metaGroup object/relation for every item in the list)
```

If i have some item ID and no item is loaded yet, i can request it from the database, eagerly loading everything i need: sqlalchemy will join group, its items and corresponding metaGroups within single query. If i'd access them with default lazy loading, sqlalchemy would need to issue 1 query to grab an item + 1 to get group + 1*#items for all items in the list + 1*#items to get metaGroup of each item, which is wasteful.

2.1) But what if i already have Item object fetched, and some of the properties which i want to load are already loaded? As far as i understand, when i re-fetch some object from the database - its already loaded relations do not become unloaded, am i correct?

2.2) If i have Item object fetched, and want to access its group, i can just getGroup using item.groupID, applying any eager statements i'll need ("items" and "items.metaGroup"). It should properly load group and its requested relations w/o touching item stuff. Will sqlalchemy properly map this fetched group to item.group, so that when i access item.group it won't fetch anything from the underlying database?

2.3) If i have following things fetched from the database: original item, item.group and some portion of the items from the item.group.items list some of which may have metaGroup loaded, what would be best strategy for completing data structure to the same as eager list above: re-fetch group with ("items", "items.metaGroup") eager load, or check each item from items list individually, and if item or its metaGroup is not loaded - load them? It seems to depend on the situation, because if everything has already been loaded some time ago - issuing such heavy query is pointless. Does sqlalchemy provide a way to track if some object relation is loaded, with the ability to look deeper than just one level?

As an illustration to 2.3 - i can fetch group with ID 83, eagerly fetching "items" and "items.metaGroup". Is there a way to determine from an item (which has groupID of an 83), does it have "group", "group.items" and "group.items.metaGroup" loaded or not, using sqlalchemy tools (in this case all of them should be loaded)?

Comment: Since Item.ID is a primarykey you should be able to replace .filter(Item.ID == int(lookfor)).one() with .get(int(lookfor))

Comment: Thanks for advice, i'll try such replacement. The reason of using such construction is simple - i cut alot of irrelevant code from example, in full version fetching of an object can be done not just via primary key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To force loading lazy attributes just access them. This the simplest way and it works fine for relations, but is not as efficient for `Column`s (you will get separate SQL query for each column in the same table). You can get a list of all unloaded properties (both relations and columns) from `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.instance_state(obj).unloaded`.

You don't use deferred columns in your example, but I'll describe them here for completeness. The typical scenario for handling deferred columns is the following:

- Decorate selected columns with `deferred()`. Combine them into one or several groups by using `group` parameter to `deferred()`.
- Use `undefer()` and `undefer_group()` options in query when desired.
- Accessing deferred column put in group will load all columns in this group.

Unfortunately this doesn't work reverse: you can combine columns into groups without deferring loading of them by default with `column_property(Column(…), group=…)`, but `defer()` option won't affect them (it works for `Column`s only, not column properties, at least in 0.6.7).

To force loading deferred column properties `session.refresh(obj, attribute_names=…)` suggested by Nathan Villaescusa is probably the best solution. The only disadvantage I see is that it expires attributes first so you have to insure there is not loaded attributes among passed as `attribute_names` argument (e.g. by using intersection with `state.unloaded`).

**Update**

1) SQLAlchemy does track loaded objects. That's how ORM works: there must be the only object in the session for each identity. Its internal cache is weak by default (use `weak_identity_map=False` to change this), so the object is expunged from the cache as soon as there in no reference to it in your code. SQLAlchemy won't do SQL request for `query.get(pk)` when object is already in the session. But this works for `get()` method only, so `query.filter_by(id=pk).first()` will do SQL request and refresh object in the session with loaded data.

2) Eager loading of relations will lead to fewer requests, but it's not always faster. You have to check this for your database and data.

2.1) Refetching data from database won't unload objects bound via relations.

2.2) `item.group` is loaded using `query.get()` method, so there won't lead to SQL request if object is already in the session.

2.3) Yes, it depends on situation. For most cases it's the best is to hope SQLAlchemy will use the right strategy :). For already loaded relation you can check if related objects' relations are loaded via `state.unloaded` and so recursively to any depth. But when relation is not loaded yet you can't get know whether related objects and their relations are already loaded: even when relation is not yet loaded the related object[s] might be already in the session (just imagine you request first item, load its group and then request other item that has the same group). For your particular example I see no problem to just check `state.unloaded` recursively.

Comment: As i mentioned in comment to Nathan Villaescusa's reply, accessing attribute will do if i need to load only top-level relationships w/o getting deeper. As for unloaded set of attributes - thanks. Is there sqlalchemy InstanceState docs which list attributes like 'unoaded'? I didn't find such docs at official site but it seems i need such low-level functions for proper object completion and other performance savings.

Comment: Could you provide your requirements in details by updating a question? Just recursively loading without depth limit doesn't seem sane: just one relation property can lead to whole database loaded into memory in some applications.

Comment: I've just made some experiments: 2.1 and 2.2 seem to be true (i.e. no re-fetching occurs in the both cases). Still need answer for 2.3 and 1 though.

Comment: @DarkPhoenix I've updated the answer, hopefully detailed enough.

Comment: Thanks, awesome - it covers everything i need.

Answer (score 4):

1)
From the [Session documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#frequently-asked-questions):

> [The Session] is somewhat used as a cache, in that
>   it implements the identity map
>   pattern, and stores objects keyed to
>   their primary key. However, it doesn’t
>   do any kind of query caching. ... It’s only
>   when you say query.get({some primary
>   key}) that the Session doesn’t have to
>   issue a query.

2.1) You are correct, relationships are not modified when you refresh an object.

2.2) Yes, the group will be in the identity map.

2.3) I believe your best bet will be to attempt to reload the entire group.items in a single query. From my experience it is usually much quicker to issue one large request than several smaller ones. The only time it would make sense to only reload a specific group.item is there was exactly one of them that needed to be loaded. Though in that case you are doing one large query instead of one small one so you don't actually reduce the number of queries.

I have not tried it, but I believe you should be able to use the  [sqlalchemy.orm.util.identity_key](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html?highlight=identity#sqlalchemy.orm.util.identity_key) method to determine whether an object is in sqlalchemy's identiy map. I would be interested to find out what calling identiy_key(Group, 83) returns.

Initial Question)
If I understand correctly you have an object that you fetched from the database where some of its relationships were eagerloaded and you would like to fetch the rest of the relationships with a single query? I believe you may be able to use the [Session.refresh()](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.refresh) method passing in the the names of the relationships that you want to load.

Comment: Yes, that's correct - i have already fetched from database object and i want to fetch its relationships in a single query (or 1 query per relationship, it doesn't matter as long as sqlalchemy can assign fetched properties to the object i'm working with). I tried refreshing as you suggested, sqlalchemy allows me to do it only for columns in the database, not relationships (i can refresh groupID of an item objeect, but i can't refresh group relationship). InvalidRequestError: No column-based properties specified for refresh operation. Use session.expire() to reload collections and related items.

Comment: I think i can try triggering lazy loading of required properties and relationships (this would mean that 1 query per object will be issued), but what if i want to go several levels deeper in relationship level? Let's take an Item as example, i can trigger lazy loading by accessing item.group <1st query>, then i want sqlalchemy to fetch all items from item.group.items list of Item objects <+1>, and metaGroup for each item <+# of items> (it would look like ("group", "group.items", "group.items.metaGroup") for eager loading) - is there way to do this using 1 query for "group" property of an item?

Comment: You could do group = Session.query(item.group).options(eagerload(...)) and completely reload the group that the item is a part of. I am curious whether at that point item.group will == group.

Comment: I just checked - yes, internal sqlalchemy mappings properly reflect loaded object (that is, item.group is == group). Is there any way to determine if some relation (say, item.group) is already fetched from the database (to avoid re-fetching data)?

Comment: I believe it is possible. See my revised question.